# How do you turn off TLS for your etcd pods?

Tags: ssl, etcd

I have a test cluster where I want to connect to ETCD pod. It does not let me because of

```
"error":"tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake"
```

I am not sure how to implement TLS for my client. Is there a simple way to disable TLS on ETCD?

According to [these docs](https://etcd.io/docs/v3.1/op-guide/configuration/) ETCD

> can be set to accept TLS traffic, non-TLS traffic, or both TLS and non-TLS traffic.

Using the [auto-tls](https://etcd.io/docs/v3.1/op-guide/configuration/#--auto-tls) flag did not help.

Comment: Did you find out?